# Setting a cookie on the TLD from a subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am pretty new to this cookie stuff. I have a requirement where I need to set a cookie on the TLD (www.example.co.uk) from one of the subdomains (sub.example.co.uk) using Javascript. First of all, is it possible? if yes, how do I go about doing that? Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
L

Comment: The spec requires cookie domains to have at least one dot. So no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confused about the definition of a [TLD](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Tld). You cannot set a cookie on a TLD. You can try to set a cookie on a different domain, but the browser may or may not accept it (look into the [P3P](http://www.w3.org/P3P/) header). I would set it in a shared domain. In your example, it would be `.example.co.uk` and would work for www.example.co.uk and sub.example.co.uk.

Try this (untested):

```
document.cookie = "name=value; expires=date; path=path; domain=.example.co.uk";
```

Comment: right, I am on sub.example.co.uk and how do I set a cookie on ".example.co.uk" was my question.

Comment: See §5 in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.3. The RFC suggest that user agent should reject the cookie set on top level domain : https://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on the server side, by loading an image from the main domain name which is actually a script setting the cookie.

so in the HTML code of sub.example.com add `<img src="http://www.example.com/spacer.php?newcookie=test" />`

then in spacer.php you read the get 'newcookie' and set it using setcookie (PHP) and include a spacer image.

It's a bit hacky, but it works.